# Redirect When Access Token Expired OAuth2

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0

Im using OAuth2 to secure my API, but i wouldn't use refresh token to get my new access token, im just want redirect to some pages when the access token is expired

[Header Response Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVLVM.jpg)

Comment: Later part of question is not clear. Please elaborate

Comment: already updated, my point is how to redirect when access token is expired :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess redirecting is easy, If your application is a server App then send the response back to browser with status 302 and LOCATION=redirect_URI?error_code=&error_desc=. You can build the error page to be JSP or even servlet which simply reads the error_code and error_description and displays it in friendly manner. Make sure that the error page is not protected by the filter which checks the token